# How to configure a client to connect to two WCF server endpoints of the same interface but in different scope?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a service that programmatically creates two net-tcp end points of the same interface but in different scope (they do different things under the hood). Normally when services run as they are supposed to, there is no problem for a client service to discover these two points properly based on the scope of each of them. However since discovery doesn't work across subnets, when testing I usually add manual configuration into my app.config to enable my app successfully register endpoints even if discovery fails (which does). Now how can I configure my app.config so that it would work for my new endpoints?

```
<?xml  version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint
                address="net.tcp://myserver:2170/"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="IMyServiceInterface"
                name="Service1"/>
            <endpoint
                address="net.tcp://myserver:2173/"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="IMyServiceInterface"
                name="Service2"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If there is a correlation between your client code and services, you can store service address in appSettings and change the URL on proxy depending upon from where in client you make the call

Comment: @Dhawalk we are using discovery and announcements in our model. Having the above configurations allows automatic pick up of extra services that discovery unable to find due to network boundaries. This mechanism is more or less what you say but doesn't require manual intervention and coding.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to make service clients with this constructor dynamically

```
public ServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
```

and push different settings manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is your problem in. I don't see why you look into interfaces on client side, since behavior should be defined on server. As per my understanding, you just need to generate your client class once (it's being done automaticaly by VS) and to use it's constructor like that:

```
var remoteAddr = "net.tcp://myserver:2173/";
var client = new MyClient("*",remoteAddr);
```

in your app.config there will be only one configuration, pointing to some default server.